# Spring cloud zuul /refresh throwing 500 error

Tags: java, spring, open-source, netflix, pcf

When I hit the /refresh endpoint of Zuul application, I get the following error and the routes added are not getting refreshed.

```
"exception": "java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException",
"message": "Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5427d309 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@5fdf1642,
"path": "/refresh
```

Tried with various spring cloud dependencies like Dalston.Release Edgware.Release and see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

set   "eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled" to false

this may help you

but /refresh still can't reload routes.